# How to update only specific field on Firebase Database on android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i was trying to update only one field when user clicks a button

here is the `database`

[image]

i need to update report_status when user clicks a button

```
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        report_value=Integer.parseInt(arrayforreport.get(posi));
            report_value++;
         databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
             @Override
             public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                 //i need to update report_status by id
             }

             @Override
             public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

             }
         });

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to update a value in your Firebase database there is no need to attach a listener, that is needed only when you need to read data.  So to update a particular node, you only need to use `setValue()` method directly on the `databaseReference` object.

So assuming that the `type` node is a direct child of your Firebase database, please use the following line of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
rootRef.child("type")
    .child("Whatsapp")
    .child("Shopping Deals")
    .child(shoppingDealId)
    .child("report_status")
    .setValue("newValue");
```

In which `shoppingDealId` is the id of a particular shopping deal. You can get this id using the following line of code:

```
String key = ref.push().getKey();
```

Answer (score 2):

`addValueEventListener` is to retrieve the value, you don't need it to set the value.

First get the key from `DatabaseReference` then use `setValue` to change the value.

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            report_value=Integer.parseInt(arrayforreport.get(posi));
            report_value++;

            DatabaseReference databaseReference = adapter.getRef(position);
            String key = databaseReference.getKey();

           databaseReference.child("type").child("Whatsapp").child("Shopping Deals").child(key).child("report_status").setValue(report_status);

        }
    });
```

Comment: adapter.getRef(postion) what this stand for can u please explain it.. is that adapter variable belongs to array adapter?? beacuse iam facing issue to get the key.. where user clicked list item

Comment: What's the problem you are facing?

Comment: i cannot possible to get the id of user selected field